# C# ; How to implement event and delegates in Remoting

Tags: .net, winforms, remoting

How to implement the user-defined events in Remoting.net ?
I tried it but ide errors.

Comment: have u tried something... ?

Comment: show us what you have tried, thanks !

Comment: "Type System.DelegateSerializationHolder and the types derived from it  are not permitted to be deserialized at this sercurity level". I don't know why ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `TypeFilterLevel` property found on your formatter sink to `TypeFilterLevel.Full`. An example and explanation can be found here:

[Automatic Deserialization in .NET Framework Remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dxse167%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)